# Vtiger 7 did not install in xampp (Php version is 7)

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I am new in Vtiger. Try to install it(version 7) in xampp which contains php 7. At the time of installation it shows too many error. The errors are as follows:

```
Warning: Declaration of Users::saveentity($module) should be compatible with CRMEntity::saveentity($module, $fileid = '') in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954
Warning: Declaration of Users::uploadAndSaveFile($id, $module, $file_details) should be compatible with CRMEntity::uploadAndSaveFile($id, $module, $file_details, $attachmentType = 'Attachment') in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954
Warning: Declaration of Users::insertIntoEntityTable($table_name, $module) should be compatible with CRMEntity::insertIntoEntityTable($table_name, $module, $fileid = '') in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954
Warning: Declaration of Users::save($module_name) should be compatible with CRMEntity::save($module_name, $fileid = '') in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954
Warning: Declaration of Users::get_column_value($columname, $fldvalue, $fieldname, $uitype, $datatype) should be compatible with CRMEntity::get_column_value($columnname, $fldvalue, $fieldname, $uitype, $datatype = '') in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 17
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 18
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 19
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 21
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 23
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 24
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 25
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 26
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 27
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 28
Notice: Undefined variable: mod_strings in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\CustomView\CustomView.php on line 29
Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\utils.php on line 337
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
Notice: Undefined variable: recordName in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\Controller.php on line 141
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: theme in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: V7_THEME_PATH in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\test\templates_c\v7\c80b4004a0cf5ddf2d75375d658848d8b45b6ea9.file.Header.tpl.php on line 40
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\test\templates_c\v7\c80b4004a0cf5ddf2d75375d658848d8b45b6ea9.file.Header.tpl.php on line 40
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
```

Installation Wizard

```
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
```

Welcome to Vtiger CRM 7 Setup Wizard

```
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
  Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
   Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
```

This wizard will guide you through the installation of Vtiger CRM7

```
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
  Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
  Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
```

Powered by vtiger CRM 7.0.0  © 2004 - 2017  vtiger.com  |

```
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
    Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
    Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
```

Read License  |

```
Notice: Undefined index: language in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\includes\runtime\BaseModel.php on line 31
 Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
 Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 677
```

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Did it pass the requirement check while installing? if yes, avoid the warnings! not really a big deal.

Comment: Unfortunately this is normal for vtiger. Either you have to turn off notice and warning reporting (which would negatively affect any other development you do on the same machine) or just deal with the 500 lines of warnings every time you open a page in vtiger and be unable to troubleshoot anything related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't errors. Those are a few warnings and a lot of Notices. Try turning them off in your php.ini. As long as you don't get **Fatal Errors** you can safely continue with the installation.

Comment: I am using 'error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING' in php.ini file but till shows few warning.

Comment: 1) Warning: Declaration of Users::saveentity($module) should be compatible with CRMEntity::saveentity($module, $fileid = '') in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954

Comment: 2) 
Warning: Declaration of Users::uploadAndSaveFile($id, $module, $file_details) should be compatible with CRMEntity::uploadAndSaveFile($id, $module, $file_details, $attachmentType = 'Attachment') in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954

Comment: 3) Warning: Declaration of Users::insertIntoEntityTable($table_name, $module) should be compatible with CRMEntity::insertIntoEntityTable($table_name, $module, $fileid = '') in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954

Comment: 4) Warning: Declaration of Users::save($module_name) should be compatible with CRMEntity::save($module_name, $fileid = '') in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954

Comment: 5) 
Warning: Declaration of Users::get_column_value($columname, $fldvalue, $fieldname, $uitype, $datatype) should be compatible with CRMEntity::get_column_value($columnname, $fldvalue, $fieldname, $uitype, $datatype = '') in D:\xampp\htdocs\vtiger7\modules\Users\Users.php on line 1954

Comment: take a look at your config.inc.php... error reporting can ve overriden there (or somewhere else). Create a file and put it at your vtiger root folder with the followin contents: `<?php phpinfo();` Execute that file from a browser, you'll see there what the error reporting configuration is and if I'm not mistaken, you can see which file that configuration is being taken from.

Comment: But either way, you can continue with the installation process even if those warnings are being displayed. It won't affect the installation. If you still have warnings and notices after installation, you can try to turn them off just as you are trying right now.

Comment: The warning effect.Because when I put db name, db user,password form and press next button then it shows a page. It is OK. But when press next then it shows installation process for few seconds and convert total page to blank page. Did not produce any error. Check phpmyadmin there did not install any table or data. How to solve it.

Comment: did you try the phpinfo() trick? Also, you can try switching to php 5.6. Vtiger 6.5 was in theory compatible with php 7, but in practice it wasn't. So  the same could be happening with vtiger 7.

Answer (score 0):

**Turn off error reporting from index page**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```